# error: Attempt to access a dead clipboard

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

Can anybody tell me what can be the cause of this error or where can I find out more about this error?

```
    event.preventDefault(); 

    try{ 
     var itemsVector:Vector.<Object> = 
event.dragSource.dataForFormat('itemsByIndex') as Vector.<Object>;
    }
     catch(errObject:Error) {
     trace(errObject.message);  
    }
```

---

It is with AIR, and happens when I try to drag items in a spark list.

```
Error: Attempt to access a dead clipboard
    at flash.desktop::Clipboard/checkAccess()
    at flash.desktop::Clipboard/getData()
    at DragDataFormatFetcher/getClipboardData()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\airframework\src\mx\managers\NativeDragManagerImpl.as:953]
    at mx.core::DragSource/dataForFormat()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\DragSource.as:199]
    at components::TLComponent/lst_dragOverHandler()[C:\Users\Artur\Documents\My Dropbox\Projects\DS\Flash\src\components\TLComponent.mxml:111]
    at components::TLComponent/__lst_dragOver()[C:\Users\Artur\Documents\My Dropbox\Projects\DS\Flash\src\components\TLComponent.mxml:154]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:12266]
    at spark.layouts.supportClasses::LayoutBase/dragScroll()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\layouts\supportClasses\LayoutBase.as:1773]
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Comment: Can't find an explanation about the error - can you post the code that caused it? Is it AIR or Flex? What were you trying to do with clipboard?

Comment: Thank you for the comment Amarghosh. I can't find an explanation either.

Comment: What are you doing in `lst_dragOverHandler()` function at line number 111 of `TLComponent.mxml` file? Post that function or the relevant part thereof

Comment: I reduced it to this and it still happens. The try/catch catches the error.